# Server.UrlEncode for SQL?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, filenames, urlencode

Is there a way I can do .NET's `Server.UrlEncode()` function using SQL Server 2008?

I'm looking for a way of formatting text a user has submitted for File Name purposes using the `@Name` the user has provided rather than having to convert application end, then send both `@Name` and `@FileName`.

I hope this makes sense cheers

Comment: Are you asking how to use CLR integration to invoke this method or how to simulate it in TSQL?

Comment: While you can do this, I find it much less problematic if you store all database strings unencoded and only do encoding (whether for URLs, JavaScript, SQL, whatever) immediately before you use it, such as in your ASP.Net front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to perform [Percent-Encoding/Decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which is defined in [Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) of [RFC 3986, titled "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

You can use this section to determine how to percent-encode/decode URIs in T-SQL.

Specifically, you'll want to pay attention to all of [Section 2: Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) with specific attention paid to [Section 2.4: When to Encode or Decode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4).

The best way to do this, of course, is to perform this before/after you save/query the database.  Relational databases in general aren't made for this kind of computational work.

If you use code, you might want to take a look at the [Microsoft Web Protection Library on CodePlex](http://wpl.codeplex.com/), as it contains mechanisms for percent-encoding/decoding which are much more up-to-date in regards to taking into account vulnerabilities that can arise from poor encoding schemes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation in pure T-SQL:

[T-SQL UrlEncode](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_debetta/archive/2007/03/09/t-sql-urlencode.aspx)